# Attribute Error in Python: Setting y ticks to minutes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe and I am plotting a bar graph using this dataframe. Basically, I want to visualize hourly average duration of travel. I am trying to change the y-ticks to minutes but I keep getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'MinuteLocator' object has no attribute 'set_locs'

This is my code:

```
from matplotlib.dates import MinuteLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(MinuteLocator())
ax.bar(df.x, df['time_minutes'], width=25, align='center')
```

My dataframe has an index from 0 to 23 named 'x' (designating the hours) and one column for the travel duration (e.g. 00:05:01.602679). I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: A locator cannot be used as formatter. Did you mean to use `set_major_locator(MinuteLocator())`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I updated the code. I was able to plot the bar graph but there are no yticks. :(

Comment: Can you make sure the question is self-consistent? See [mcve]. Currently noone can run that code and hence one cannot find out about the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reminded! I'll go edit the question.